# SQL parsing string of address with spaces and commas into seperate fields

Tags: sql, string, parsing, sql-server-2012

I have this list of data:

```
    ADDRESS
    '204 W 8th St, ABC, New York, NY 12345-6789'
    '222 N Barley St, Pittsburh, Pennsylvania, PA 98765-4321'
    '1 S Main St, Good Day, Washington, PA 13579-2468'
    '232 Justin Blvd, Sacramento, CA 86420-7531'
```

Where I would like to parse into 5 fields ie Mail Address 1, Mail Address 2, City, State, Zip Code. I been able to parse some of these individual though not correctly such as:

```
    select distinct StreetName =
    substring(ADDRESS, CHARINDEX(',', ADDRESS+',', 1) +1,
    CHARINDEX(',', ADDRESS+',', CHARINDEX(',', ADDRESS+',', 1) +1) -
    CHARINDEX(',', ADDRESS+',', 1) -1)
    from Bills
    where ISNUMERIC(LEFT(ADDRESS,1))=1
    AND LEN(ADDRESS) > 1
```

which gets me mail address 2 mostly. How can I do this so that the string is separated into 5 columns?

Comment: So you want the string separated into 5 separate columns?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I would like to do

Comment: Are you able to use `parsename()` and `replace()` functions?

Comment: I also was able to get this for the code:
       SELECT LEFT(PAY_TO_ADDR, CHARINDEX(',', PAY_TO_ADDR+',')-1)
FROM CS_BILL_DISB_BASE

Comment: I have never used them to be honest. I am not limited in what I can use but I am not experienced in functions

Comment: `CHARINDEX(',', ADDRESS+',', 1)` makes me feel like `address` may have no commas at all. Or you only need ones with at least 3 commas as in your example?

Comment: I only need the commas in the example of my string data `ADDRESS` to help parse but then there has been the trouble with the zipcode and the sometimes null value of the second part of the address.

Comment: imo, you are going to have loads of trouble parsing addresses with SQL. it doesn't have real good text parsing support, and there are many gotchas.

Comment: Understood. It definitely would be easier in different environment. They only part I now can't get is the zip to separate away from the State Code

Answer (score 1):

Parsing address may be rather tricky task and I realy don't know all the rules. I'll just show how to make calculations step by step in SQL much like in other programming languages. Use CROSS/OUTER APPLY.

```
select sd.addr, t.*, tt.*, ttt.*
from (
   select '204 W 8th St, ABC, New York, NY 12345-6789' as addr
) sd
cross apply(
    select nParts = len(addr) - len(replace(addr,',',''))
    , lastPos = len(addr) - charindex(',', reverse(addr),1) +1
    , secondPos = charindex(',' ,addr,1)
    ) t
cross apply(
    select first = left(addr, secondPos-1)
    ,middle = substring(addr, secondPos+1, lastPos - secondPos -1)
    ,last = right(addr, len(addr) - lastPos )
    ) tt
outer apply( 
    select thirdPos = charindex(',' , middle ,1)
    ,forthPos = len(middle) - charindex(',', reverse(middle),1)+1
    where nParts >3    
    ) ttt
```

and so on. Add steps and logic as needed.